# will gwbasic run on 32 bit windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dos, gw-basic

XP getting hard to find , will gwbasic, qbasic, dos programs run on windows 7 , 32 bit

Cant try it dont have a windows 7 computer

I thought about buying all parts in a computer that ran windows dos programs. The cost likely less than a new computer and my hard ware works with the ports